# PC unusable after deleting files from WindowsApps

Tags: windows-10

One problem led to another, so I really needed to perform a system restore and unfortunately I am aware that my pc has always had a problem with this and I just can't restore. So I set out to fix this issue so I would able to use this feature.

The error was:

```
System Restore did not complete successfully. Your computer's system files and
settings were not changed.

Details:
System Restore failed while restoring the directory from the restore point.
Source: AppxStaging
Destination: %ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps
An unspecified error occurred during System Restore. (0x80070091)
```

Then some forums including a microsoft one (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93a0d2a2-d9f1-4b57-97b9-0ca30de656aa/system-restore-failed-source-appxstaging-error-0x80070091?forum=win10itproapps) had a suggestion that you could delete or rename the C:/Program Files/**WindowsApps** folder.

Specific procedure is noted here 
[image]
So I did this and then rebooted and realised hey, my pc has a black screen and a cursor and nothing else.

One minor problem led to the pc being unusable. Willing to try anything? But it seems like I'm going to have to install windows again :'(

The folder didn't get deleted for some reason access is denied but I believe it deleted 99% of the files that were in it.

Comment: So what's the problem at the moment? What does unusable mean

Comment: When given a choice between delete “forever”, or rename “temporarily” why would you choose delete forever? I hope you get it figured out but this is a lesson learned hopefully.

Comment: Why would you delete every single UWP application on your system?  The folder by default has the permissions it does for a reason.  There is no simple solution to this problem.  You attempted a bad solution to a problem that wouldn’t have solve been solved by that solution by the way.

Comment: At the moment when I boot all I see is a black screen and a cursor. I couldn't rename anyway because it said access denied.